# how to add more widgets into this form? (django-oscar)

Tags: python, django, image, forms, upload

I know that oscar has already set up their own templates and forms but I want to override / edit some parts and having a hard time finding where to do the modification in order to get what I want.

There's is a regular form like below and I circled it in black that I want to add more widgets into the form tools such as upload an image so when people create / edit the product, they do have an option to upload images while editing / adding the product.

[image: product form]

Sorry the form is being translated to Chinese but anyways the translation shouldn't be a trouble.

Can someone lead me how I am able to add something like an image uploader here?

Thanks in advance people.

Comment: Had did you try changing the editor js plugin?